# how to save big png file in R?

Tags: r, cairo

I've saved png files in R successfully using the following comands.

```
png("myfile.png",width=1000,height=400)
plot(myX,myY)
dev.off()
```

But, when I try to save a png file with I huge size like that:

```
png("myfile.png",width=1000,height=400000)
plot(myX,myY)
dev.off()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in png 
unable to start device 'png'

cairo error 'invalid value (typically too big) for the size of the input
```

Anyone knows how to save huge png files in R?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If the reason is resolution, maybe try a vector format like pdf or svg.

Comment: I'm using Linux (ubuntu).